# Can I use .NET classes from JScript.NET without import statement?

Tags: .net, import, jscript.net

How can I use classes without having to `import` the namespace in JScript.NET?

E.g. I want to be able to write `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ping");` instead of:

```
import System.Windows.Forms;
MessageBox.Show("Ping");
```

Is there a way to do this in JScript.NET?

Answer (score 0):

@Anon suggested using WScript.Shell instead of System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show. I think what s/he was trying to communicate is that, if you are after a one-liner, you're not going to get it using assembly notation. However, if you're willing to hook into ActiveX, then a one-liner equivalent is as follows:

```
(new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")).Popup('Ping');
```

BTW, I have been fiddling for a while, trying to get a pure .NET solution figured out, but so far it has eluded me.

And, if this page about [ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is anything to go by, it should probably be assumed that JScript.NET does *NOT* automatically import a large swathe of namespaces.

Answer (score -1):

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

WshShell.Popup(Text, WaitSeconds, Title, Type);
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?  You should always provide some context or description with your answer to explain why this solution would work.